# Reasons for allowing התר מכירה in this day and age

Tags: halacha, transactions, shmita, real-estate, shaat-hadechak

Here is the concluding paragraph from an article from Torah L'Daat (red volume, BeHar 'בענין אם יש קנין לנכרי בארץ ישראל להפקיע קדושת שביעית') that discusses the halachic boundaries of whether non-Jews can acquire land in Israel to remove the obligation of Shvi'it. The article, in general, outlines the basis for heter mechira.

> ‏… היתר זה של הב״י הי׳ היסוד להיתר המכירה שהונהג משנות תרמ״ט—תרנ״ו ואילך. אמנם, הרבה גדולים התנגדו למכירה מטעמים אחרים, ואפילו המתירים התירו למכור לעכו״ם רק בשעת הדחק גדולה כשהי׳ נוגע לפיקוח נפש ממש, ולא התירו לחלוטין אלא בשביל שמיטה אחת לבד, ובשמיטה הבאה הוצרכו לישב בדין עוד פעם לברר אם השעה דחוקה כ״כ עד שהוצרכו לסמוך על היתר מכירה.…‏
>
> … This [heter](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/585) of the Bet Yosef was the basis for the heter of sale that was practiced from the years 5649 to 5656 and thenceforth. However, many great rabbis opposed the sale for other reasons, and even those who allowed selling to a non-Jew did so only in a great time of pressure where it was relevant to actual preservation of life. They allowed it not absolutely but for one Shvi'it alone and required the following Shvi'it that people sit in judgement again to determine whether the time was so pressing as to require reliance upon the heter of sale.…

The condition brought to allow heter mechira is that it must be only at a 'very pressing time' (שעת הדחק גדולה) where 'lives are at stake'. Do battei din that permit heter mechira use other clauses to allow heter mechira? Or do we indeed live in a time where lives are at stake and we permit heter mechira?

Comment: ["Today agriculture represents 2.5% of total GDP and 3.6% of exports. While agricultural workers make up only 3.7% of the work force, Israel produces 95% of its own food requirements, supplementing this with imports of grain, oilseeds, meat, coffee, cocoa and sugar."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture_in_Israel) That's a huge amount of national money. We're already relying on aid from the US to run our military, an essential for proper defense.

Comment: This is more Shaat HaDechak than most people's chametz sales...

Comment: @DoubleAA, but we're assured that if we let the land lie fallow for _sh'mita_ then God will provide. So where's the _d'chak_?

Comment: @msh210 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35536/can-one-test-god-with-shmita#comment92464_35536 in particular, and the question in general. Note that expecting such a public and document-able miracle like that nowadays would be even more extreme, given the lack of those recently. (Note further that if your answer worked even the Rabbis 150 years ago would have had no basis for relying on Heter Mechira.)

Comment: Rav shlomon zalman in his hakdama to maadanei arutz has not only the history but also the halachic issues involved

Comment: As @Nafkamina already mentioned, read through the מעדני ארץ of the Rosh Yeshiva, Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach זצ"ל who permitted Heter Mechira in this day and age. (He was Niftar about 20 years ago.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann i wouldnt say the Rav Shlomo Zalman was matir for noawadays, he was matir the concept, but not in the full practical sense

Comment: to OP i truly suggest getting a fabulous Feldheim book called "Rebels in the Holy Land" written by Sam Finkel it tells the story and backround of the Shmitta Controversy in the latter part of the 19 century. He also dicusses the issues at hand in a very succinct way

Comment: @msh210, An interesting question would be whether that assurance applies when שמיטה is דרבנן.

Comment: @Ephraim, yes: see DoubleAA's comment in reply to mine, above.

Comment: @nafkamina ,if you have access to a Yitzchak Yikareh Mishna Brurah by Rav Nebontzol see in back of chelek 6 in Shiviis 1 which quotes the opinion of Rav Shlomo Zalman .

Comment: what does it say there?

Answer (score 2):

Rav Ovadia Yosef states that the sefardi poskim allow heter mechira, regardless of if it is a shaas hadchak. He also quotes that Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach paskened in favor of heter mechira.
In his sefer שו"ת יביע אומר
ח"י),
Rav Ovadia, states  clearly that it is 100% permitted in this day, and that is regardless of whether it is a time of sakana. But for those who are machmir, blessing will come to them.

I dont think that it is easy to say that it is a 1 dimensional issue,  it clearly has many issues that need to be taken into account, such as if we are machmir will we be causing farmers to sin.